# Argument of type 'int' is not iterable when I use tuples

Tags: python

I am getting this error when I run my program and I have no idea why. The error is occurring on the line that says `if prt in migration_p[j][0] and dst in migration_p[j][1]`

```py
migration_p = [(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 3)]
link = {(1, 2): 200, (1, 3): 50, (2, 3): 100, (1, 4): 300, (2, 4): 100, (3, 4): 50}
source_servers = {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3]}
partition = {1: 200, 2: 200, 3: 500}


def time_qi(dst, prt):
    global size, bandwidth, min_time, source

    tqi_rsrc = []
    indexes = []
    for i in source_servers.keys():
        if (i, dst) in link.keys():
            bandwidth = link[i, dst]
        for j in range(len(migration_p)):
            if prt in migration_p[j][0] and dst in migration_p[j][1]:
                size = partition[prt]
                tqi_rsrc.append(bandwidth / size)
                indexes.append(i)

    min_time = min(tqi_rsrc)
    index = np.argmin(tqi_rsrc)
    source = indexes[index]
    # print(source)

    return min_time, source

print(time_qi(3, 1)[0])
```

Comment: `in` is used to check if the value is contained in a collection. You should either be doing `prt in migration_p[j]` (checking if it is in the tuple), or `prt == migration_p[j][0]` (checking that it is equal to the first item in the tuple). And similarly with `dst`.

Comment: `migration_p[j]` is a tuple like `(1, 3)`, and `migration[j][0]` is `1`. So you're testing `prt in 1`, and you can't do `in` on an `int`.

Comment: you can't iterate int to int change in to == . `if prt == migration_p[j][0] and dst == migration_p[j][1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prt` and `migration_p[j][0]` are both integers. You have to use `==` instead of `in`:

```
if prt == migration_p[j][0]
```

`in` is used to check if a value is present in an iterable object. If you want to use `in`, you have to do:

```
 if prt in migration_p[j]
```

but be aware this can also match the other value in the tuple now.